# prompt user to login to protected directory in python

Tags: python, directory, windows-explorer, windows-security

I have a script that searches through a protected directory and opens file explorer to a selected location. The problem is that it only works after the user has already logged into the directory.

Example of what sort of thing the code is doing below:

```
subfolder = input("give a subfolder")

if os.path.isdir("\\\\directory\\path\\"):
    #run some stuff
    os.startfile("\\\\directory\\path\\" + subfolder)
else:
    print('error message- unable to connect to drive. Please log in')
```

If the user has opened "\\directory\path" on their own and entered their username/password into the windows security prompt, then my code works. If they haven't, I can't find the directory path.

Is there a way to open to the [windows security prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZkgE.png) from Python? Ideally user puts in username and password and then can continue to the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [install win32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), you can connect to network resources with a prompted username and password.  It's not a simple solution (like an `os` call), but you can use the wnet_connect method from [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/) to pass a username/password in your `except` call.

It boils down to:

```
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(0, None, full_path, None, username, password)
```

Comment: Perfect, that does it! If I add the connection and then try to open to that directory it will work and authenticate perfectly fine.